# React Native TextInput Comp. Doesn't Work on Specific location in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, debugging, react-native

EDITED. 
So, guys, you told me just write one question at a time. Now I fixed my little bugs but still, I have a bug that's so weird.

Now, I can't click on TextInput comp. in android below a specific location on the screen. To be clear;

when the styling is like that: -WORKS

```
input: {
    position: 'absolute', // probably it's about position, but I'm not sure
    top: 29, // I mean when top style prop is smaller than 30 it works
    width: '92%',
    height: 30,
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'left',
  }
```

However when it's like this: -DOESN'T WORK

```
input: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30, // or 35 or 40
    width: '92%',
    height: 30,
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'left',
  }
```

And, I don't think it's necessary but this is the TextInput comp:

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({input: text.toLowerCase()})}
    value={this.state.input}
    />
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.sendButton} onPress={()=> this.handleSubmit()}>
      <View>
        <Icon name="send" color="#fff" size={30}/>
      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
```

So, if you guys have any clue that you think it will be helpful, I'm listening with four ears :) Thanks in advance! Sorry for late edit :(

Comment: Please post the code where there is a problem.

Comment: @Emirhan Kaplan, please make your description clear and simple, and don't ask many questions in one time

Comment: @Lenoarod I added the whole code.

Comment: @hongdevelop I added the whole code.

Comment: @EmirhanKaplan  Why use 'position' when you are in a parent's view? This is not a good way.

Comment: @hongdevelop you're right :) I'll try that.

Comment: @hongdevelop I did what you said and weirdly now it works on 30,31,32,33 but still not on 34 or greater :/ but I think I need to idealize my code maybe I'm doing something wrong... thanks anyway!

Comment: @EmirhanKaplan I advised you not to use position. But why use `top`?

Comment: @hongdevelop I used the position in parent view. I tried not to use a position at all, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: now I kinda fix it. when I change the height of the parent view I have more range in positions. but it doesn't make any sense :( claps for you, @hongdevelop you helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

please post the code where you're facing issues.

Comment: This is an opinion. Don't post it in your answers.

Comment: @hongdevelop I can't post in comments.